# docker build of Dockerfile fails

Tags: docker

Docker fails to build from [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/). I am using the sshd example. I am seeing the same problem on multiple environments. I have also tried clearing cache `rm -rf /var/lib/docker` and restarting docker but still get stuck at the same location everytime.

OS: `Linux localhost x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 00:31:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Docker Version

```
Client version: 1.0.0
Client API version: 1.12
Go version (client): go1.2.2
Git commit (client): 63fe64c/1.0.0
Server version: 1.0.0
Server API version: 1.12
Go version (server): go1.2.2
Git commit (server): 63fe64c/1.0.0
```

Docker build command output.

```
[root@sandbox eg_sshd]# docker build -t eg_sshd -rm=true --force-rm=true --no-cache=true .
Warning: '-rm' is deprecated, it will be replaced by '--rm' soon. See usage.
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.56 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM ubuntu:12.04
Pulling repository ubuntu
822a01ae9a15: Download complete 
... 
f6a1afb93adb: Download complete 
 ---> 822a01ae9a15
Step 1 : ENV https_proxy http://proxy-src.research.ge.com:8080
 ---> Running in 6c868ad4ca77
 ---> 485232bcd98d
Removing intermediate container 6c868ad4ca77
Step 2 : ENV http_proxy http://proxy-src.research.ge.com:8080
 ---> Running in a703af701009
 ---> 44064f7741ff
Removing intermediate container a703af701009
Step 3 : MAINTAINER *********
 ---> Running in 88713ce9495d
 ---> 11d12b77f4ab
Removing intermediate container 88713ce9495d
Step 4 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 3afe877dfae1
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]
...
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [130 kB]
Fetched 28.4 MB in 34s (828 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Removing intermediate container 3afe877dfae1
2014/08/13 15:46:15 Driver devicemapper failed to get image rootfs 68529afd0618533ada99f9566f2ac34b655de277ce77b237cb2947d408596739: Unknown filesystem type on /dev/mapper/docker-253:0-131162-68529afd0618533ada99f9566f2ac34b655de277ce77b237cb2947d408596739
```

Comment: It looks like a docker bug. There is the following issue which might be related: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4036  I suggest you either add a comment on that issue or open a new one.